# Maven install error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

```
Running me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveWorkflowServiceTest
2017-06-23 15:49:58,230  INFO [main] support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.loadProperties:181 | Could not load properties from class path resource [application.test.local.properties]: class path resource [application.test.local.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2017-06-23 15:49:58,464  WARN [main] support.GenericApplicationContext.refresh:487 | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-test.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    at  ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-test.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    at ... 43 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.231 sec <<< FAILURE!
testAllPass(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveWorkflowServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-test.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    at  ... 43 more

Running me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.web.user.UserControllerTest
2017-06-23 15:49:58,470  INFO [main] support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper.getTestExecutionListeners:182 | Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@3129f63e, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@39e579a9, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@89663f1, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@497b679e, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@44cfdbc2]
2017-06-23 15:49:58,473  INFO [main] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions:317 | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-test.xml]
2017-06-23 15:49:58,629  INFO [main] support.GenericApplicationContext.prepareRefresh:510 | Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@2a64c0d9: startup date [Fri Jun 23 15:49:58 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-23 15:49:58,655  INFO [main] support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.loadProperties:172 | Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]
2017-06-23 15:49:58,655  INFO [main] support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.loadProperties:172 | Loading properties file from class path resource [application.test.properties]
2017-06-23 15:49:58,655  INFO [main] support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.loadProperties:172 | Loading properties file from class path resource [application.test.local.properties]
2017-06-23 15:49:58,656  WARN [main] support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.loadProperties:181 | Could not load properties from class path resource [application.test.local.properties]: class path resource [application.test.local.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2017-06-23 15:49:58,657  WARN [main] support.GenericApplicationContext.refresh:487 | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-test.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    at Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    at  ... 43 more
2017-06-23 15:49:58,658 ERROR [main] context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance:215 | Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@39e579a9] to prepare test instance [me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.web.user.UserControllerTest@95e60cf]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at  ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.dialect' in string value "${hibernate.dialect}"
    at  ... 43 more

Results :

Failed tests:   testWithWebservice(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveWebserviceInWorkflowTest): expected:<1> but was:<0>
  testWithWebserviceFalse(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveWebserviceInWorkflowTest): expected:<1> but was:<0>

Tests in error: 
  testUserData(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.dao.InitDataTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  allClassMapping(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.dao.JpaMappingTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  crudEntity(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.dao.LeaveDaoTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testProcessEngines(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.engine.ProcessEngineTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testSave(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveManagerTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testWithWebservice(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveWebserviceInWorkflowTest): Error parsing XML
  testWithWebserviceFalse(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveWebserviceInWorkflowTest): resource 'diagrams/leave-webservice.bpmn' not found
  testAllPass(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.service.oa.leave.LeaveWorkflowServiceTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testUserExistInDb(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.web.user.UserControllerTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testUserNotExistInDb(me.kafeitu.demo.activiti.web.user.UserControllerTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 12, Failures: 2, Errors: 10, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.160 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-23T15:49:58+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/357M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDtEm.jpg)

There are some errors of them,I import the maven project,set the jdk version and dynamic web module version so on,when I maven clean and next step install,maven return the error imformation,according to hints,I have saw all errors point to hibernate dialect,and could not resolve "hibernate dialect" in String value $(hibernate.dialect).Then I have found the XMLfile "application-test.xml" and check out what's wrong!But I don't know the reason not OK if the setting like this!Who can tell me why or how to solve the problem about the setting.Thank you!

Comment: Place the application.test.local.properties file with hibernate dialect information in resource folder. The error says property file not available so not able to resolve hibernate properties.

Comment: first of all please read how to ask questions. and provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your hibernate properties to the application.properties file and/or your test-application.properties file. At least hibernate.dialect is missing. Search google (StackOverflow) for the right dialect for the DB you're using.